# SQL Server Pivot Before Current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and have the below that forms part of a much larger statement to calculate the total of each month in a field called 'This_Year'.  This works fine:

```
SELECT        
pvt.*, 
Isnull(pvt.jan_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.feb_CY, 0) + 
Isnull(pvt.mar_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.apr_CY, 0) + 
Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jun_CY, 0) + 
Isnull(pvt.jul_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.aug_CY, 0) + 
Isnull(pvt.sep_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.oct_CY, 0) + 
Isnull(pvt.nov_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.Dec_CY, 0) AS This_Year
FROM
(SELECT        Account AS [GL_Code], AccountDesc AS [GL Desc].......
```

My question is I have being tasked with amending this to exclude the current month from the total based on whatever the current month is at the time.

So at the moment (in December) I only need to calculate everything up to and including November.  In January it will be everything up to and including December and so on.

What will be the best way to approach this?  Will I need to perform a CASE for each scenario i.e. When Current month = 12 only add 1+2+....11 etc?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I worked it out:

```
SELECT        
pvt.*, 
CASE
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 5 THEN Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0)
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 6 THEN Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0) 
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 7 THEN Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jun_CY, 0)
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 8 THEN Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jun_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jul_CY, 0)
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 9 THEN Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jun_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jul_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.aug_CY, 0)
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 10 THEN Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jun_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jul_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.aug_CY, 0)+Isnull(pvt.sep_CY, 0)
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 11 THEN Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jun_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jul_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.aug_CY, 0)+Isnull(pvt.sep_CY, 0)+ Isnull(pvt.oct_CY, 0)
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 THEN Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jun_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jul_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.aug_CY, 0)+Isnull(pvt.sep_CY, 0)+ Isnull(pvt.oct_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.nov_CY, 0) 
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 THEN Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jun_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jul_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.aug_CY, 0)+Isnull(pvt.sep_CY, 0)+ Isnull(pvt.oct_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.nov_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.Dec_CY, 0) 
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 THEN Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jun_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jul_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.aug_CY, 0)+Isnull(pvt.sep_CY, 0)+ Isnull(pvt.oct_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.nov_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.Dec_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jan_CY, 0)
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 3 THEN Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jun_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jul_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.aug_CY, 0)+Isnull(pvt.sep_CY, 0)+ Isnull(pvt.oct_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.nov_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.Dec_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jan_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.feb_CY, 0)
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 4 THEN Isnull(pvt.may_CY, 0)+ Isnull(pvt.jun_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jul_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.aug_CY, 0)+Isnull(pvt.sep_CY, 0)+ Isnull(pvt.oct_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.nov_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.Dec_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.jan_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.feb_CY, 0) + Isnull(pvt.mar_CY, 0)
end as This_Year 
FROM
(SELECT        Account AS [GL_Code], AccountDesc AS [GL Desc].......
```